# CSS HTML 1 big square box divide into 4 box with full background image, hover to certain box will change background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a homepage that is only 1 big square box inside have 4 small square box with no margin in it. but the background image is covered the whole square box. when hover to certain square box, it will change the whole background image.

for example, https://www.mdnsonline.com/ . this website is divide into 4 vertical rectangle, but i want to make it 4 equal square.. could someone helping on this?

thank you so much.. here is what i doing but seem like not perfect..

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

section img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a+img {
  opacity: 1;
}

ul li a:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: animate 20s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url('/shop') }}"></a>
      <img src="{{ asset('frontend/images/slides/17/slide-03.jpg') }}" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url('/about-us') }}"></a>
      <img src="{{ asset('frontend/images/slides/17/slide-04.jpg') }}" alt="">
    </li>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url('/contact-us') }}"></a>
      <img src="{{ asset('frontend/images/slides/17/slide-05.jpg') }}" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url('/') }}"></a>
      <img src="{{ asset('frontend/images/slides/17/slide-06.jpg') }}" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: I would recommend to first try something yourself and then come back with what you already got. We are here to help but this is not a hired-coder platform. If you come up with something yourself, post it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or so and the relevant parts here on SO and you'll most likely get help.

Comment: Aaaah, I can definitely code all this for you, but you'll have to hire me :) However if you show your attempts and your code, and tell us exactly where you're stuck, we can help you for free!

Comment: sorry guys, i already edit in my code, im new to css and html, seems like cant make some box and align..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to start with CSS grid. I've but together a minimal example here to show you how it would work.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    hi
  </div>
  <div>
    hi
  </div>
  <div>
    hi
  </div>
  <div>
    hi
  </div>

</div>
```

Then for your css:

```
div.grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 8px;
}

div div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}
```

Which will give you a result like this:

[image: grid layout]

Modify the gap, number of columns etc to achieve the same effect. In order to get the background hover, add an image to each div and give it the 'scale' property on hover. This should give you that zoom effect they show off. I'll update the answer to show this later.

Comment: thank you so much! looking forward to your answer and i will try myself too.. thank you once again.

Comment: No problem. Make sure you upvote / accept answers that are helpful to your question :-)

Comment: Thanks mate, the grid is coming out but i wonder why the background image covered the box,